# Deshabilitar ONLY_FULL_GROUP

Tags: mysql-8.0

Han cambiado en el servidor a Mysql8 y se ha caído la web. Nos recomiendan:

> La recomendación es que modifiques todas las sentencias de SQL que no cumplen con la restricción de ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY. Pero entendemos que revisar los desarrollos no siempre es sencillo o rápido, por lo que una solución alternativa pasa por deshabilitar ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY en el código de tu conexión a MySQL 8.
> Por motivos de seguridad, compatibilidad y mantenimiento en hosting compartido no modificamos el modo de SQL por defecto en el servidor, pero tú puedes modificarlo en el inicio de sesión dentro de tu programación.
> Por ejemplo, en PHP, utilizando un código como este al conectar a la base de datos MySQL 8:
> `mysqli_options($mysqlconn, MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND, ‘SET @@SESSION.sql_mode = NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION’);`

Hemos implementado esto en el *configuration.php*

```
}
//* set connection options */

$sql = "mysqli_options($mysqlconn, MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND, ‘SET @@SESSION.sql_mode = NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION’)";

}
```

No funciona,

Comment: Si la respuesta te funcionó marcarla como aceptada, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo de dos modos:

### 1) Mediante `mysqli_options()`

Si vas a usar `mysqli_options()`, debes hacerlo después de  `mysqli_init()` y antes de `mysqli_real_connect()`, [como indica el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.options.php), ver también los ejemplos de código en [`mysqli_real_connect()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-connect.php).

El orden sería este:

```
$mysqlconn = mysqli_init();
mysqli_options($mysqlconn, MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND, ‘SET @@SESSION.sql_mode = NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION’);
mysqli_real_connect($mysqlconn, 'localhost', 'mi_usuario', 'mi_contraseña', 'mi_bd');
```

### 2) Mediante el constructor (`new`) o mediante `mysqli_connect()`

Si conectas de esta forma, entonces puedes mandar a ejecutar mediante `query()` una consulta que cambie ese parámetro en la sesión, una vez te hayas conectado.

Algo así más o menos:

```
$mysqlconn = new mysqli('localhost', 'mi_usuario', 'mi_contraseña', 'mi_bd');
$sql="SET @@SESSION.sql_mode = NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION;";
$mysqlconn->query($sql);
```

Es evidente que si usas `mysqli_real_connect()` ya no usarás `new mysqli()` o `mysqli_connect()` para conectar a la base de datos o viceversa.

### Deshabilitar `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` no es una solución definitiva, ni la mejor solución

No obstante, debes prestar mucha atención a [lo que dice el Manual de Referencia de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) sobre deshabilitar `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`:

> If `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is disabled, a MySQL extension to the standard
> SQL use of `GROUP BY` permits the select list, `HAVING` condition, or
> `ORDER BY` list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns
> are not functionally dependent on `GROUP BY` columns. This causes
> MySQL to accept the preceding query. In this case, the server is free
> to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the
> values chosen are nondeterministic, which is probably not what you
> want. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be
> influenced by adding an `ORDER BY` clause. Result set sorting occurs
> after values have been chosen, and `ORDER BY` does not affect which
> value within each group the server chooses. Disabling
> `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is useful primarily when you know that, due to
> some property of the data, all values in each nonaggregated column not
> named in the `GROUP BY` are the same for each group.

---

> Si `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` está deshabilitado, una extensión de MySQL
> para el uso estándar de SQL de `GROUP BY` permite que la lista de
> selección, la condición `HAVING` o la lista `ORDER BY` se refieran a
> columnas no agregadas incluso si las columnas no dependen
> funcionalmente de las columnas `GROUP BY`. Esto hace que MySQL acepte
> la consulta anterior. En este caso, el servidor es libre de elegir
> cualquier valor de cada grupo, por lo que, a menos que sean iguales,
> los valores elegidos no son deterministas, lo que probablemente no sea
> lo que desea. Además, la selección de valores de cada grupo no puede
> verse influenciada por la adición de una cláusula `ORDER BY`. La
> clasificación del conjunto de resultados se produce después de que se
> hayan elegido los valores, y `ORDER BY` no afecta qué valor dentro de
> cada grupo elige el servidor. Deshabilitar `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` es
> útil principalmente cuando sabe que, debido a alguna propiedad de los
> datos, todos los valores en cada columna no agregada no nombrada en
> `GROUP BY` son los mismos para cada grupo.

Convendría entonces deshabilitar `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` como último recurso, pero sin perder de vista escribir tus consultas según el estándar, o, en algunos casos, estarás dejando a la libre elección del SGBD los datos que deben mostrarse, pudiendo tener una información que no es la esperada en muchos casos.